# SharePoint Customization; Web Part v. Workflow

Tags: sharepoint

How do I determine whether I should code my customizations as a web part of as a workflow.  I am calling out a different system from this feature to trasmit a state change.  This is something that needs to be relatively real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webparts in sharepoint are like components...
while workflow are like flowchart, they can be used to as process.

[Workflows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010154424.aspx)

[Webparts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/CH010372434.aspx)

if u have series of steps go for workflow..

else go for webparts

Answer (score 0):

I use workflows primarily for features that contact other systems, they're more 'independent' and you can persist and 'try again later' if the "other system" isn't available.